# hadoop plugin for eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, hadoop, eclipse-indigo, cloudera, hadoop-plugins

I downloaded and setup hadoop-cdh3u2 from cloudera. inside hadoop-0.20.2-cdh3u2/src/contrib i found a project called "eclipse-plugin" and I imported it in eclipse, got error, and added hadoop-core.jar runed as a eclipse application, but i can't add a new server (do i need to update anything in "MANIFEST.MF")??. I m getting the following error. And i want to know export this project into jar is normal process, or do i need to do anything extra???

eclipse version is indigo, platform Ubuntu 11.10, java version is 1.6

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
    at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.server.HadoopServer.<init>(HadoopServer.java:223)
    at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.servers.HadoopLocationWizard.<init>(HadoopLocationWizard.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.actions.NewLocationAction$1.<init>(NewLocationAction.java:41)
    at org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.actions.NewLocationAction.run(NewLocationAction.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.Action.runWithEvent(Action.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1258)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3588)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3209)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 33 more
```

Answer (score 1):

surendhar, eclipse plugin will not work with hadoop 0.20.203.* check here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7382

Comment: surendhar, thier is section in the Hadoop wiki which helps you get the updates search here http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipsePlugIn   Also, look into the comments sections in this link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-7382?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#issue-tabs